# Raspberrypi reboots when i run my python3 code

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

While i run the tensorflow object detection python3 code on my raspberrypi 3B then after 1mits the pi reboots without showing any videos.

https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/Object_detection_picamera.py

Comment: the links should be used as backup because if they break they could make your question unusable, in your case the link is used to share the code, one of the most important parts of your question if the link breaks in the future Do you think your question will still be useful?

Comment: Perhaps you should setup CPU and Memory profiling for your application

Comment: Oh really!!! Thanks alot and can you please tell me how to setup CPU and memory profiling for my application?

Comment: How are you powering the Pi? If the power cable is too thin (high resistance), if the power supply is less than 1 amp or if it doesn't consistently output 5 volts, that would cause brown-outs and reboots.

Comment: Hey it WORKED!! thanks jDo 

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys after the help of one of the stackoverflow mate i was able to fix it. 
What happened was My power supply only provided 1amp and 5v, but to run my code it required more amps, about 1.8 so when i connect 2amp 5v power supply it worked finally